# Finite difference - wave equation - boundary conditions and setting things up

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation-solving, finite-element-analysis

I am working on a project that has to do with solving the wave equation in 2D (x, y, t) numericaly using the central difference approximation in MATLAB with the following boundary conditions:

[image: plot]

The general assembly formula is:

[image: FDformula]

I understand some of the boundary conditions (BC), like

du/dy=0 at j=m,

[image: BC],

but I am not sure how to implement these boundary conditions in MATLAB.

A friend has given me these equations:

[image: eq]

Here is my try with the MATLAB code,
but I am not able to progress any further:

```
% The wave function
% Explicit 

% Universal boundary conditions for all 3 cases:
% u=0 at t=0
% du/dt=0 at t=0

% Case 1 boundary conditions
% At x=0, u=2sin(2*pi*t/5);
% At y=0, du/dy=0;
% At y=2, du/dy=0;
% At x=5, du/dx=0;
% u=0 and du/dt=0 at t=0;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------%


% Setting up
clc; clear all; close all;

% length, time, height
L = 5; % [m]
h = 2; % [m]
T = 10; % [s]

% Constants
c_x = 1; % arbitrary 
c_y = 1; % arbitrary

dx = 0.1; % <x> increment
dy = 0.1; % <y> increment
dt = 0.1; % time increment
nx = L/dx + 1; % number of <x> samples
ny = h/dy + 1; % number of <y> samples
nt = T/dt + 1; % number of time samples
t(:,1) = linspace(0, T, nt); 

theta_x = c_x*(dt^2)/(dx^2); 
theta_y = c_y*(dt^2)/(dy^2); 
% theta_x = theta_y
theta = theta_x;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------%

% The matrix 
U = zeros(nt, nx, ny);

% Setting up the <U> matrix with the boundary conditions - case 1
U(1, :, :) = 0; % U=0 at t=0

for tt=1:nt   % U=2sin(2pi/5*t) at x=0
    for jj=1:ny
        U(tt, 1, jj)=2*sin(2*pi/5.*t(tt));
    end 
end


for it=2:t
    for ix=2:nx-1
        for iy=2:ny-1
            % Boundary conditions

            % General case (internal):
            U1 = -U(it-1, ix, iy);
            U2 = 2*(1-2*theta)*u(it, ix, iy);
            U3 = theta*U(it, ix-1, iy);
            U4 = theta*U(it, ix+1, iy);
            U5 = theta*U(it, ix, iy-1);
            U6 = theta*U(it, ix, iy+1);



        end 
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The general assembly formula you have kind of applies to the boundaries as well.
The complication is that when you apply the formula when `j = 1` and `j = m`, you have `j = 0` and `j = m+1` term that are off of your grid.

To ameliorate this problem, boundary conditions give you a relationship between the points off the grid and on the grid.

As you have indicated, the `dudy = 0` condition has given you the relation that `u(i,m-1) == u(u,m+1)` on the boundary.  So you use the general assembly formula and replace all of the `m+1` terms with `m-1` *on the boundary*.  You'll have a similar relation for the lower boundary as well.